# WixToolset: Avoid LGHT0204 : ICE64 for folders in the user's AppDir when the installer is not the one to create those folders?

Tags: wix

I am building an installer for a tool that adds on to an existing application using scripting.  The main application uses folders in the user's AppDir, and I want to add a subfolder and some files:

```
        <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
          <Directory Id="ProgAppDataDir" Name="ProgName">
            <Directory Id="ScriptsDir" Name="Scripts">
              <Directory Id="SCRIPTINSTALLDIR" Name="ProductName"/>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
```

In this setup, the AppDataFolder is Wix's shortcut to %AppData%.  The main application creates the "ProgramAppDataDir" and "ScriptsDir".  Then I create the "SCRIPTSINSTALLDIR" for my use.  I add `<RemoveFolder Id="SCRIPTINSTALLDIR" On="uninstall" />` in the appropriate component, but since I didn't install the other directory, and they can contain content that should not be removed during uninstalling my application, I don't want to add the same for the ProgAppDataDir and ScriptsDir.

Since I don't do that, I get the following error messages when using light:

```
error LGHT0204 : ICE64: The directory ProgAppDataDir is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
error LGHT0204 : ICE64: The directory ScriptsDir is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
```

Is there a way to avoid these errors?  Either create a link to the path that doesn't trigger the ICE error, a way to suppress these as known / accepted errors, or some other way around them?

I have seen several related posts, such as the ones listed below but they all suggest adding the RemoveFile directive or relate to missing / orphaned ids which is not appropriate for this case.

[wix The directory is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627861/wix-the-directory-is-in-the-user-profile-but-is-not-listed-in-the-removefile-tab)

[remove file ICE64 writing to localAppData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595103/remove-file-ice64-writing-to-localappdata)

[How do I install to LocalAppData folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102771/how-do-i-install-to-localappdata-folder)

[Why does WiX complain that my directory isn't listed in the RemoveFile table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212879/why-does-wix-complain-that-my-directory-isnt-listed-in-the-removefile-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RemoveFolder` only removes empty folders, so it's appropriate for your case like the others.